# R Shiny Error: Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am using the following code and I always get this subsettable error unless if I run the line

`df <- read.csv("./world-happiness-report-cleaned.csv")`
manually before running the app. What am I subsetting, and where am I wrong? I can't seem to find the error, and I'm super new to Shiny so I've never had to deal with this before. Thank you so much!!

This link is to a filebin that has the csv I used: https://filebin.net/wjctohctz1sxm16y

server.R

```
# Elit Jasmine Dogu, ejd5mm
# Project One DS 3002
library(dplyr)
library(countrycode)
library(shiny)
df <- read.csv("./world-happiness-report-cleaned.csv")

    #saveRDS(df, "./df.RDS")
server <- function(input, output) {
    #reading in the data and basic data cleaning 
    #df<- read.csv("world-happiness-report-cleaned.csv")
    #df <<- readRDS("./df.RDS")
    #df <- read.csv("./world-happiness-report-cleaned.csv")
    
    # Filter data based on user selections
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
        data <- df %>%
            filter(
                if(input$year != "All") {
                    Year ==input$year
                } else {TRUE}
            ) %>%
            filter(
                if(input$country != "All") {
                    Country ==input$country
                } else {TRUE}
            ) %>%
            filter(
                if(input$continent != "All") {
                    Continent ==input$continent
                } else {TRUE}
            )
        
        return(data)
        
    }))
        # Generate a summary of the dataset (on the left panel)
        output$summary <- renderPrint({
            data <- df %>%
                filter(
                    if(input$year != "All") {
                        Year ==input$year
                    } else {TRUE}
                ) %>%
                filter(
                    if(input$country != "All") {
                        Country ==input$country
                    } else {TRUE}
                ) %>%
                filter(
                    if(input$continent != "All") {
                        Continent ==input$continent
                    } else {TRUE}
                )
            
            return(summary(data))
            
        })
    
       #Generate a function to show the number of rows w/ any given dataframe selection/restriction
    rows = function() {
        data <- df %>%
            filter(
                if(input$year != "All") {
                    Year ==input$year
                } else {TRUE}
            ) %>%
            filter(
                if(input$country != "All") {
                    Country ==input$country
                } else {TRUE}
            ) %>%
            filter(
                if(input$continent != "All") {
                    Continent ==input$continent
                } else {TRUE}
            )
        
        return(nrow(data)) #returns number of rows of the data
    }
    
    #Generate a function to show the number of columns w/ any given dataframe selection/restriction
    cols = function() {
        data <- df %>%
            filter(
                if(input$year != "All") {
                    Year ==input$year
                } else {TRUE}
            ) %>%
            filter(
                if(input$country != "All") {
                    Country ==input$country
                } else {TRUE}
            ) %>%
            filter(
                if(input$continent != "All") {
                    Continent ==input$continent
                } else {TRUE}
            )
        
        return(ncol(data)) #returns the number of columns of the data
    }

    #Using the functions created above
        output$columns  <- renderText({
            paste("Number of Columns:" , cols() ) #text to display the number of columns
        })
        output$rows  <- renderText({
            paste("Number of Rows (Records):" , rows() ) #text to display the number of rows 
        })

        output$data_ex  <- renderText({
            paste("Please see README.md file for information regarding the dataset.") #text to display where to find more information
        })
 

        # Downloadable csv of selected dataset 
        output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
            filename = function() {
                selected <-c() #this assists with the name of the file
                if (input$year != "All") { 
                    selected <-c(selected, input$year)
                }
                if (input$country != "All") {
                    selected <-c(selected, input$country)
                }
                if (input$continent != "All") {
                    selected <-c(selected, input$continent)
                }
                if (length(selected) == 0) {
                    selected <- c("AllData")
                }
                
                paste0(paste(selected, collapse="-"), ".csv")
            },
            content = function(con) {
                data <- df %>%
                    filter(
                        if(input$year != "All") {
                            Year ==input$year
                        } else {TRUE}
                    ) %>%
                    filter(
                        if(input$country != "All") {
                            Country ==input$country
                        } else {TRUE}
                    ) %>%
                    filter(
                        if(input$continent != "All") {
                            Continent ==input$continent
                        } else {TRUE}
                    )
                write.csv(data, con, row.names = TRUE) #saves the filtered data
            }
        )
}
```

ui.R

```
# Elit Jasmine Dogu, ejd5mm
# Project One DS 3002
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    #text with project name and my information
    titlePanel("World Happiness Report"),
    tags$h3("DS 3002- Project One"),
    tags$h4("Elit Dogu, ejd5mm 3rd Year UVA"),
    # use a gradient in background, setting background color to blue
    setBackgroundColor(  
        #https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/setBackgroundColor.html used this website for help on background color
        color = c("#F7FBFF", "#2171B5"),
        gradient = "radial",
        direction = c("top", "left")
    ),
    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(
        
        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(
            
            # Output: Header + summary of distribution ----
            h4("Summary"),
            verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
            
            # Download button
            downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
        ),
    # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

    fluidRow(  #manipulates the original dataframe given user selection
        column(4,
               selectInput("year",  #selection for the year variable
                           "Year:",
                           c("All",
                             unique(as.numeric(df$Year))))
        ),
        column(4,
               selectInput("country",  #selection for the country variable
                           "Country:",
                           c("All",
                             unique(as.character(df$Country))))
        ),
        column(4,
               selectInput("continent",  #selection for the continent variable
                           "Continent:",
                           c("All",
                             unique(as.character(df$Continent))))
        )
    ),
    # Create a new row for the table
    DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
    
    # Create a new column for the text to be displayed
    column(12,
           verbatimTextOutput("columns") #column to display col count
    ),
    column(12,
           verbatimTextOutput("rows") #column to display row count
    ),

    column(12,
           verbatimTextOutput("data_ex") #column to display more information text
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Thank you!!

Comment: In your `rows` and `cols` functions, you are accessing `input$` directly. This is wrong for at least two reasons: (1) your functions are breaching scope, reaching out to things they were not explicitly passed. (2) `input$` can *only* be accessed from within a `reactive*`, `observe*`, or `render*` block (i.e., something that is shiny-reactive). Nothing outside any of those should try to do anything with `input$` or `output$`. As a fix, consider `rows = function(year, country, continent) { if (year != "All") ...}`, then `paste(..., call(input$year, .....))`.

Comment: Hello! I'm super new to Shiny but that makes a lot of sense! Thank you! I'm a little confused as to where the fix would be implemented?

Comment: See my answer ...

Comment: @r2evans That's true, but is it the reason here? I've also noticed that the OP weirdly uses `renderDataTable`: there's a `return` statement inside the `datatable` function.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, while perhaps nonstandard, I don't know that that is a problem. Good point, though.

Comment: @r2evans This is like doing `f <- function(x){x+1}; f({y <- 2; return(y)})`. That does not work.

Comment: I don't doubt it. I don't use `return` all that often, and I don't have a quick-easy shiny app sitting around for a quick test, so I was being non-committal. I understand the premise (doesn't work in `{`, `for`, `while`, etc), just hadn't tested completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `df$......` inside the UI. If you define `df` inside the `server` function, it is not defined in the UI. So you get this error because R recognizes `df` as the function provided by the 'stats' package (an object of type "closure" is a function).

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. I'm guessing that `input$` might cause problems as well, but yours is likely the culprit.

Comment: JasmineDogu, this is a common problem for new users in R: when naming variables the same as a function, when the script is re-run without creating that variable, R finds an object named for the data you think you have, but it is a function instead. Know that a "closure" is a function and its surrounding environment, so what your error is telling you is that you cannot `$`-subset a function.Try `mean$a`, for instance.

Comment: Thank you so much! Putting df in the UI helped solve the issue. I had tried this before and it had not worked, but I was able to get it working this time! Seems like this was the issue. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @JasmineDogu You can put `df <- read.csv(......)` in the file `global.R` instead of putting it in both ui and server.

Answer (score 1):

**Up front**: [StéphaneLaurent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67062755/3358272) is the first thing you need to fix. Below is not causing *that error*, though I still recommend the changes for other reasons.

---

In your `rows` and `cols` functions, you are accessing `input$` directly. This is wrong for at least two reasons:

1. (general functional programming) Your functions are breaching scope, reaching out to things they were not explicitly passed. This *can* be a bit about programming style, but functions that use variables not explicitly passed to it can be difficult to troubleshoot.
2. `input$` can *only* be accessed from within a `reactive*`, `observe*`, or `render*` block (i.e., something that is shiny-reactive). Nothing outside any of those should try to do anything with `input$` or `output$`.

As a fix, make the functions agnostic to shiny by making them self-contained and just working scalars/vectors. (I'll also reduce the logic a little.)

```r
  #Generate a function to show the number of rows w/ any given dataframe selection/restriction
  rows = function(year, country, continent) {
    data <- df %>%
      filter(
        year == "All" | year == Year,
        country == "All" | country == Country,
        continent == "All" | continent == Continent
      )
    return(nrow(data)) #returns number of rows of the data
  }

  # ...

  output$rows  <- renderText({
    paste("Number of Rows (Records):" , rows(input$year, input$country, input$continent) )
  })
```

Frankly, your `cols` function is a little odd ... you can change the number of rows of a frame all day long, but the number of columns does not change. Unless you `dplyr::select` some columns away, it should always be exactly `ncol(df)`.

As for the reduction of logic, your `if` statements embedded within your `dplyr::filter` chain aren't wrong, but I think the more R-idiomatic way to do it is what I've suggested. In your case, if a variable is `"All"`, then it returns a single `TRUE`, which `dplyr::filter` applies to all rows. If not, then it returns a `logical` vector (1 for each row) indicating if the frame's variable matches the selected input.

In my version, I do something very similar: the first `year == "All"` will still resolve to a single logical (assuming `year`, from `input$year`), but the right-hand-side will be as long as the number of rows. You can test what this looks like:

```r
TRUE | c(T,F,T,F)
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
FALSE | c(T,F,T,F)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fix! Unfortunately, my app still wont run unless I run the line where the csv is read before running the app. Is there any fix for that? Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't know how you're running this, nor how you intend to handle the data. Are you testing by deploying to shinyapps.io or similar?

Comment: When I implement the method you suggested for the cols and rows functions, the rows function works great, but the text for the columns disappears. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm running it in R Studio. When I try to deploy to shinyapps.io it won't deploy unfortunately and I believe the error comes from how my csv file is read in. For some reason, in R Studio the app only runs if df is already in the workspace environment

Comment: When you deploy to shinyapps, you must include the csv file as well, and in the same directly. If you aren't doing that, then your next option is to have the app download that csv file from somewhere, I'm not sure if it's something you can operationalize in a sense.